# Find Common Rows for some Row Values in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with Ids and a subId column. And I have a user defined data type with a list of SubIds. I want all those ids which have all the sub-ids present in my user-defined data type. for example:
The table is:

```
 ID     SubID     
 1        2     
 1        3
 1        4
 2        3
 2        4
 2        2
 3        3
 3        2
```

and the data type is

```
 CREATE TYPE SubIds AS TABLE   
( SubId INT );  
GO
```

With Value

```
SubID
  3
  4
```

I want the output to be

```
  ID
   1
   2
```

Because only the ID 1 and 2 contain both the subIds 3 & 4

Note: the combination of Id and Sub ID will always be unique if its of any use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
select ID
from yourtable 
Where SubID in (3,4)
Group by ID 
having Count(distinct SubID)=2
```

Another more flexible approach

```
select ID
from yourtable 
Group by ID 
having sum(case when SubID = 3 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
   and sum(case when SubID = 4 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```

If you want to pull `SubId's` from `SubIds` table type then,

```
SELECT ID
FROM   yourtable T
       JOIN (SELECT SubID,
                    Count(1) OVER() AS cnt
             FROM   SubIds) S
         ON T.SubID = S.SubID
GROUP  BY ID,Cnt
HAVING Count(DISTINCT T.SubID) = s.cnt
```

Comment: SubID will not only have these two values.. It can be hundreds of different values

Comment: @RohitRaj - Do you want to pull the `SubId's` from `SubIds` table type ?

Comment: Yup, I have tried the first query earlier. It won't exactly work when SubIds as other Ids may have the same number of SubIds and has atleast one same SubIds in the table type. In such cases, it will return more Ids than required

Comment: In the above case it will return 3 also as it has subid as 3 and count of subid as 2

Comment: I have made some changes to the values. http://rextester.com/live/SPOF64358 It is giving wrong results

Comment: @RohitRaj - In result, we have 3 Id's `2024889,2036063,2036064` all three of them are having `535785` and `531614`. I don;t understand what is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that `@s` is your table of ids:

```
select t.ID
from t 
Where t.SubId in (select SubId from @s)
group by t.Id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @s);
```

This assumes that the two tables do not have duplicates.  If duplicates are present, you can use:

```
select t.ID
from t 
Where t.SubId in (select SubId from @s)
group by t.Id
having count(distinct t.SubId) = (select count(distinct s.SubId) from @s s);
```